# How to associate a unique ui-sref to every items in a dynamic list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a pagination system composed of items I retrieve from a JSON file. I can add/remove any of them. I want to associate to each of these items a link to a configuration view (each item has the same template but it has to have his own configuration). I'm looking for a proper way to do this using `ui.router`. Here's what my routing looks like :

#### app.js :

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state("itemslist", {
            url:"/itemslist",
            views: { 
                'launcher':{
                    controller:"ItemsListCtrl",
                    templateUrl:"ItemsList.html"
                }
            }
        })
        ...
}
```

And the html file :

#### ItemList.html :

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in listItem">
        <b>{{item.text}} -</b>
        <button ui-sref="dynamic state">CONFIG.</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here the 'dynamic state' could be something like "config?item.id". How would the routing work in this case ? Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use state params: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing

```
ui-sref="config({itemId: item.id})"

$stateProvider.state("config", {
    url:"/itemconfig/:itemId",
    ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting something way more complicated but this works fine ! Also, do you have an idea on how to get only the `:itemId` with the $location service ?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer: use the $stateparams service in your controller - it will be at $stateparams.itemId